# MC as dynamic content engine for external website

Tags: marketing-cloud

I think that I can engineer MC to build dynamic content blocks and serve this up to our external websites.

Ex. Serving related content based on the state you live in.

The only method I can think of that is viable would be passing in url variables, displaying the content, scraping the content and displaying in the external website.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: This is not really what SFMC is built for - There are many other software and services out there designed specifically for this that would likely meet your needs better (CMS/CRM). I would look into those prior to trying to duct tape together something using SFMC.

Comment: Yes I agree. We are looking at different options. Marketing Cloud Interaction Builder is one of those. Very cool but expensive.

Comment: Interaction Studio is the correct title.

Answer (score 2):

Up until recently, the only way of proving personalisation on web using MC was Predictive Intelligence (Einstein Recommendations). This was not ideal, as this was focused on showing articles or products based on online behaviour, and was very little rule based.

Interaction Studio is able to orchestrate and serve content on all owned channels, and is much more suited to what you are looking for, as it can a.o. make decisions based directly on customer data, without involving predictive engines.

The product has been launched recently (earlier this year) and I have not yet have any hands on experience. However it is a better match with your use case than any of the other features of SFMC

For smaller setups, 3rd party solutions such as https://www.monoloop.com might be interesting. I know Monoloop has built a connector to SFMC, enabling them to use data from there to drive personalisation within their engine on any website. I am not familiar with other products with this functionality, but there might be others offering same set of features.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your input. I viewed a demo of Interaction Studio and was very impressed. This product is more of a large enterprise solution and is cost prohibitive for us. Still very impressive!

Comment: Updated the answer with another suggestion, involving a 3rd party solution